# Исключается ли код неиспользуемых функций при подключении библиотек?

Tags: c++, c

Вопрос насчет теории языков с/с++. Например, если я подключаю математические функции через `#include <math.h>`, и использую только одну какую-нибудь функцию (допустим, `sin`), то бинарный файл итоговой программы будет содержать все функции из `<math.h>` или только одну функцию `sin`?

Comment: о какой памяти вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Линковщик оставит лишь то, что используется (справедливо для статической линковки). Если нужны уточнения, пишите в комментариях к ответу, не нужно редактировать вопрос с обращениями к отвечающим.

Comment: Какой линкер? Как  связывается - статически или динамически?

Comment: @ixSci я не знаю, когда я пишу #include <math.h> -- это статический или динамический линкер? или это просто код, который я добавляю к проекту.

Comment: `#include` просто вставляет текст упомянутого файла. Просто как `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V`.

Comment: Тут вопрос в том, что и как используется. К примеру, есть у нас некоторая библиотека (пусть это будет Qt). У нас есть 2 варианта её использования: либо мы используем DLL/SO/DYLIB (динамическая версия библиотеки), либо же LIB/A (статическая версия). В первом случае, мы не может уменьшить размер — мы всегда таскаем с собой динамическую версию, а во втором можем — линкёр видит все места использования функций и может исключить из результирующего исполняемого файла те функции, что не используются.

Comment: Поэтому, в общем случае, код слинкованный с библиотекой статически даст выходной размер программы меньше, чем если бы использовалась динамическая версия оной. Но это лишь одна сторона медали, есть и другие — это довольно обширная тема. А по вашему вопросу, всё зависит от того, какая версия библиотеки используется компилятором и что вообще за библиотеки нужны результирующему бинарнику (они зависят от используемого компилятора).

Comment: @ixSci, как раз наоборот, размер выходного файла будет значительно меньше в варианте динамической компоновки. Вы, наверное, пытались сказать про занимаемое место в памяти? Но здесь снова имеются одни бенефиты, если эта библиотека используется 2+ программами.

Comment: @0andriy, нет, я имел в виду ровно то, что сказал. Я не говорил про размер выходного файла, я говорил про размер программы, в который входят все файлы, необходимые для её запуска. Насчёт занимаемого места в памяти: это входит в другую сторону медали, которую я упомянул в том же комментарии. Всё-таки на эту тему, если по уму, можно статью написать (а можно и не одну). Я всего лишь упомянул часть, которая, как мне показалось, наиболее релевантна автору прямо сейчас.

Comment: Автор, Вы приняли как верный ответ пользователя Harry, но этот ответ является не верным. Верным является ответ alexolut.

Comment: @KtoTo Прошу вас, дабы не поднимать здесь очередную holy war, снять птичку с моего ответа, а я его удалю. Не вижу смысла во вселенской буче из-за спора, с какой стороны разбивать яйцо :)

Comment: @ixSci, бессмысленно говорить *про размер программы, в который входят все файлы, необходимые для её запуска* в варианте динамической компоновки. Не находите?

Comment: @0andriy, не нахожу. Сравните размер программы с Qt прилинкованной динамически и статически.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если у вас имеется несколько модулей (объектных файлов), то для получения итогового исполнимого файла их нужно объединить. Такой задачей занимается компоновщик. Правила работы компоновщика не описаны в стандартах языков *C* или *C++*. Но элементарная проверка может ответить на ваш вопрос применимо к конкретному компоновщику. Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    typedef double (*F)(double);
    F f[] = {sin, cos};
}
```

Я проверил результат сборки с помощью *QtCreator* и *MinGW 5.6.2 32bit* на *Windows 7* со включенной отладочной информацией. Получил такие результаты:

- `F f[] = {sin, cos}; // 50 031 байт`
- `F f[] = {sin, sin}; // 49 546 байт`
- `F f[] = {sin, 0};   // 49 546 байт`
- `F f[] = {0, 0};     // 48 373 байт`

Можно видеть, что уменьшение кол-ва разных функций приводит к снижению размера итогового исполняемого файла. Т.е. линкер выкинул явно неиспользованные функции из объектного файла.

В некоторых случаях, чтобы исключение неиспользуемого кода из библиотек было более эффективным, библиотека должна быть собрана с указанием специфических ключей. Например, для *Visual C++* таким ключом является [`/Gy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43.aspx). Он обеспечивает упаковку функций, необходимую компоновщику для достижения желаемого эффекта. Без данного ключа, компоновщик оперирует модулями (объектными файлами), а не функциями внутри библиотеки.

Comment: Нет, просто в библиотеке синус и косинус лежат **в разных объектных файлах**. Вот он и подсосал в первом случае - 2 файла, во втором и третьем - один, в четвертом - ни одного.

Comment: @Harry может и так, а может и в опциях при сборке библиотеки дело, как это оказалось для VC. Т.о. при правильной настройке сборки библиотеки реально выкинуть всё неиспользуемое, **даже внутри одного объектного файла**.

Comment: Пожалуйста, допишите о ключах и о том, что по умолчанию как минимум в VC++ соответствующий механизм отключен. И, если нетрудно, тогда приведите пример, который нельзя трактовать иначе (тот, что приведен сейчас - можно).

Comment: @Harry, только что сгенерировал новый консольный проект в 2017 студии — `/Gy` выставлен там по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Все, и в EXE и в память процесса соответственно тоже.

Только math.h не библиотека, а заголовочный файл, его подключение само по себе ничего не меняет, это для компилятора, вряд ли там есть что-то компилируемое, это был бы бардак.